# Layout changes not animating with animateLayoutChanges=true?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm guessing that I've overlooked something simple, but I'm not seeing it.

I have a set of images views that transition from visibility.gone to visibility.visible, but when I set the properties from my code, the imageviews just pop on, they don't transition smoothly.

The code that changes the visibility is just:

```
              for (ImageView button : buttons.values()) {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toc_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/junglebackground"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

    android:alpha="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:alpha="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.025">

            </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.225">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TOCR1C1"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"

                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ff_balloon"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.225">
             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TOCR1C2"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ff_anteater"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.225"
 >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TOCR1C3"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ff_birds"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.225"
  >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TOCR1C4"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:src="@drawable/empty_image"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.025"
   ></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.025"
     ></LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.225"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TOCR2C1"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_image"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.225"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TOCR2C2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/chimp_frame_toc"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.225"

 >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TOCR2C3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/dreams_frame_toc"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.225"
         >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TOCR2C4"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_image"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.025"
         ></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem did you figure it out?

Answer (score -1):

You should use ViewPropertyAnimator for this purpose. Here is a blog post on Google Android Developers Blog: [Introducing ViewPropertyAnimator](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html)

The idea is to implement the animation as Fade In and Fade Out effect. The code would be something like this:

```
//fade out 

for (ImageView button : buttons.values()) {

    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button,
          "alpha", 0f);
      fadeOut.setDuration(2000);
      fadeOut.start();
}

//fade in

for (ImageView button : buttons.values()) {

    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "alpha",
      0f, 1f);
      fadeIn.setDuration(2000);
      fadeIn.start();
}
```

Check the blog post to download a sample code and a Video demo.

Another tutorial can be found on [Vogella Android Animation](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html)